# couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Tags: apt, lubuntu, root

Fresh install of Lubuntu

Installed updates from synaptic

Installed wine and components from synaptic, upon what I assume is completion it popped this error code.

Is it something I should rush to fix?

Comment: I faced with this error when I am downloading the package. It is related with this bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1543280) and I ran `apt-get install --download-only <packageName>` instead of `apt download <packageName>`

Comment: I had  similar problem when trying to upgrade zoom. Opening the .deb in software center GUI only showed the option to remove the old version, while trying to update with `sudo apt install zoom_amd64.deb` started to update the existing installation but failed with the error message mentioned above.

Comment: apt-get install --download-only <packageName> won't download the package if it is already installed, so this is not equivalent

Answer (score 31):

This is a known bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1543280

They suggest running the following command:

```
sudo chown _apt /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/
```

Give it a try and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: This can not work on 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)