# apt install of a .deb package on lubuntu 22.04 shows the error: user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Tags: apt, 22.04, lubuntu, deb, teamviewer

My distribution is lubuntu 22.04. I know that this question seems a duplicate of other questions (for example [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954862/couldnt-be-accessed-by-user-apt-pkgacquirerun-13-permission-denied)) but none answer is working on lubuntu 22.04.
Furthermore I'm trying to install a program from a `.deb` file and not from the lubuntu repository.

#### The installation command

I'm trying to install teamviewer by a `.deb` file and I'm using the following command:

```
sudo apt install ./teamviewer-host_15.48.4_amd64.deb
```

#### The message at the end of the installation

The installation starts, but at the end, it shows the following message:

```
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/path/to/teamviewer/file/teamviewer-host_15.48.4_amd64.deb'
couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

The message starts with `N:` so I don't know if it is an error or a warning.

#### My attempts

I have tried to apply the solution proposed in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908800/what-does-this-apt-error-message-download-is-performed-unsandboxed-as-root/908825#908825), so before the execution of the command `sudo apt install` I have changed the owner and the permission of parent directory and the `.deb` file  by the commands below:

```
sudo chown -Rv _apt:root /path/to/teamviewer/file/
sudo chmod -Rv 700 /path/to/teamviewer/file/
```

But this doesn't avoid the message at the end of the installation.

[This other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771936/permission-error-when-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-cant-drop-privileges/863986#863986) gives a solution not different from the previous so it doesn't work.

I have tried also the instructions showed by [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1543280/comments/27) but the problem remains.

I have verified the existence of the user `_apt` on my system by the command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep apt
```

which gives the following output:

```
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

#### The difference of my question from other questions

Could be a difference between my problem and the problems describes by previous posts: I'm trying to install from a `.deb` file and not from official repository of lubuntu.

#### My question

The (error) message starts with `N:` not `E:` or `W:`, and TeamViewer seems working, but I'm not sure that the program is correctly installed in all its part.
Someone could give me some other info about this problem in the lubuntu 22.04 distribution?

Comment: I think `N:` just stands for `Note`. Not even a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you need to use is not apt but dpkg, in  the folder with the file:

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer-host_15.48.4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: @stanreas Thank you very much: with `dpkg -i` the installation seems always correct and the message disappears. I didn't know that the installation of `.deb` file must be execute by `dpkg` instead `apt`.

Comment: apt just uses dpkg under the hood. Also, possible [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403337/download-is-performed-unsandboxed-as-root-as-file).